# Is it possible to deﬁne a non-generic subclass of Collection?

Tags: java, collections

Is it possible to deﬁne a non-generic subclass of Collection? Why or why not?

Could I do something like:

public class NonGenericClass extends Collection{...}

Comment: Did you try it and got a compile error?

Comment: You can do `class NonGenericClass extends Collection<Object>`.

Comment: Was hard to test because the class requires so many methods to be implemented. It's a homework question I got, asking us to explain why or why not it is possible to define a non-generic subclass of Collection.

Comment: Any IDE will auto-generate the methods for you. But the answer is, yes, of course.

Comment: If you take the question literally, it is impossible to create subclasses of `Collection`, as `Collection` is an interface. You can *implement* a `Collection`. If you take the freedom to interpret the question in a way that it becomes meaningful, you can simply subclass an existing collection type to achieve the goal without the need to implement all methods.`class Test extends ArrayList<String> {}` is a valid class declaration. And so is `class Test extends ArrayList<String> implements Collection<String> {}`.